# Installing Eclipse(eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz)?

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse(eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz). How do I install it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extract it where you want it (home/user):

```
tar xzf eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz
```

It will extract the folder eclipse and the executable is inside.

Comment: Yeah I did that. But the problem was that it use to hang up many a times. I finally installed it from ubuntu software center and now things look stable(could that get the juno version there though).

Comment: It is sad but OpenJDK still has some stability issues. In companies I worked at people rather download JDK from Oracle.